# Correlation effect in Quanto options

Tags: option-pricing

My question will probably be stupid but here it is.
I try to understand the effect of the correlation between exchange rate and underlying in a quanto option.
And to have a non-precise understanding of this effect, I will consider a simple binomial tree.
Suppose I have one underlying valuing 100 \$ & current exchange rate  1€=1\$.
The quanto option pays at maturity max(S-100,0) paid in €.
I consider now two extreme cases (correlation=+/- 1):

- At maturity, S=200\$, 1€=2\$    or   S=50\$, 1€=0.5\$
- At maturity, S=50 \$, 1€=2\$    or   S=200\$, 1€=0.5 \$

In both cases, the final payoff will be 50€=0.5 * 100€+0.5 * 0€ , whatever the correlation between underlying and exchange rate is. Therefore, the current value of the option would be the NPV in € of 100 € and is independent of the correlation between exchange rate and underlying.

Where is the error in this simulation?

PS: By the way, we can use multistep binomial trees. The evolution of the underlying does not depend on the exchange rate.

Comment: I might be misreading your tree data, however, I don't even see the *terminal* payoffs being equal for your two corner cases. The OTM case is clear, 0`$` = 0`€` always. The ITM case for a correlation of +1 would pay max[200-100, 0]`$` times 0.5`€` for every 1`$`, so 50`€`. For a correlation of -1, you'd have max[200-100,0]`$` times 2`€` for every 1`$`, so 200`€`?

Comment: @KevinT that's because by definition in quanto options, the exchange rate for the final payoff is fixed at the beginning of the contract. In this case it is 1€ = 1$.

Comment: If you consider the risk-neutral measure for a trader that thinks in \$, you should have a 1/3 change of ending up at \$200 in both cases. However, would the risk neutral measure/probabilities for a trader thinking in EUR be the same here?

Answer (score 1):

The correlation comes into the replication (and thus hedging) of a quanto and not explicitly in the final payoff. In a sense you are trying to hedge a linear payoff with a linear hedging instrument (exchange rate) and a non-linear hedging instrument (foreign security converted into local currency) and the correct hedge ratio depends on the correlation.

Comment: Does this correlation still interact if we consider options paying relative performance of an index : (Final value-Initial Value)/Initial Value ?

Comment: Yes, if the accounting currency is not the natural currency of the payout (ie a quanto) then you have this effect. Your hedge instrument is still non-linear, being the product of the exchange rate and the index level.